# App crashes randomly

Tags: java, android

I'm making my first android game. It's almost complete. It runs fine most of the times without any issues, but occasionally the app stops working while going the score/highscore page. It crashes and shows the following messages in the logcat:

```
05-08 11:20:14.341 2478-2487/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/networkstatistics.sqlite' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
05-08 11:20:14.632 2478-2487/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
05-08 11:20:14.633 2478-2487/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
05-08 11:20:14.636 2478-2487/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

Could someone please tell me how to fix this?? (This doesn't always happen. It crashes sometimes).

Comment: I don't think those logs have anything to do with your game per say, they are warnings, hence `W/`. That's a google package by the way, `com.google.android.gms`

Comment: Also looking at it, I see leaks which could be memory issues;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQLite database, close the object of it for instance  **db.close()** where db is the object of datbase, also make sure you have closed the cursor object also after use, using **cursor.close()**

failing to do so, throws these kind of runtime exceptions.

Comment: What runtime exceptions is it throwing? I see Warnings

Comment: i'm using sharedpreferences

Comment: @AdnanHaqueSazin can you paste your code here, which you think is leading for the random crashes ?